# add image above listview in Android

Tags: android, listview

I've added a listview to an activity. It uses a simple layout file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dp"
android:layout_gravity="center" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/greencircle"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then I add it during the "onCreate()":

```
String[] values = new String[] { "New Contact", "List Contacts", "Edit Settings"};
        // use your custom layout
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, R.layout.activity_main_menu, R.id.label, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
      }
```

I need to put an image above the listview but I've not found anything that works. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Could you look listview header? You can setView above listView use this method.

Comment: Or you can design your layout to contain an ImageView at the top and a ListView just under it.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare it in your xml?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/detailsIco"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"      
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="7.0sp" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How do I match the your xml to the ArrayAdapter (as per the code in my question)?

Comment: items = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
items.setAdapter(adapter);